# Summarising pandas data frame by multiple fields and collapsing into a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group and summarise a pandas dataframe into a single column

| ID | LayerName | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | SC | B | 2 |
| A | SC | R | 8 |
| A | BLD | S | 7 |
| A | BLD | K | 6 |

I will like the resulting table to be summarised by the LayerName, Name and Count into a single output field like thi

| ID | Output |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 - SC : (B,R) ; 13 - BLD : (S,K) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.groupby(['ID', 'LayerName'],
            as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'Name': ','.join, 'Count': 'sum'})
   .assign(Output=lambda d: d['Count'].astype(str)
                           +' - '+d['LayerName']
                           +' : ('+d['Name']+')')
   .groupby('ID', as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'Output': ' ; '.join})
)
```

Output:

```
  ID                              Output
0  A  10 - SC : (B,R) ; 13 - BLD : (S,K)
```

Comment: "double group by and agg" sounds like a good name for a band. :)

Comment: @Scott haha, I'm in ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(["ID", "LayerName"], sort=False).\
apply(lambda x: f"{x.Count.sum()} - {x.LayerName.iloc[0]}: ({','.join(x.Name.to_list())})").\
str.cat(sep="; ")
# '10 - SC: (B,R); 13 - BLD: (S,K)'
```